# Integrity constraint (SYSTEM.FK_FACILITY) violated - parent key not found

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, foreign-keys, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm getting "integrity constraint (SYSTEM.FK_FACILITY) violated - parent key not found" error although the primary key has been clearly defined in the previous table.

```
CREATE TABLE Facility (
  facNo   CHAR(11)    NOT NULL,
  facName VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT FacilityPK PRIMARY KEY (facNo)
);
INSERT INTO Facility (facNo, facName) VALUES ('F100', 'Football stadium');
INSERT INTO Facility (facNo, facName) VALUES ('F101', 'Basketball arena');

CREATE TABLE Customer (
  custNo   CHAR(8)     NOT NULL,
  custName VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  address  VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  internal CHAR(10)     NOT NULL,
  city     VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  zip      VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  state1    VARCHAR(2)  NOT NULL,
  contact  VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  phone    VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT CustomerPk PRIMARY KEY (custNo)
);


INSERT INTO Customer (custNo, custName, address, internal, city, zip, state1, contact, phone) VALUES
  ('C100', 'Football', 'Box 352200', 'True', 'Boulder', '80309', 'CO', 'Mary Manager', '6857100');
INSERT INTO Customer (custNo, custName, address, internal, city, zip, state1, contact, phone) VALUES
  ('C101', 'Men''s Basketball', 'Box 352400', 'TRUE' , 'Boulder', '80309', 'CO', 'Sally Supervisor', '5431700');


CREATE TABLE EventReq (
  evntNo      CHAR(8)       NOT NULL,
  custNo      CHAR(8)       NOT NULL,
  facNo       CHAR(8)       NOT NULL,
  dateHeld    DATE          NOT NULL,
  dateReq     DATE          NOT NULL,
  dateAuth    DATE,
  status      CHAR(20)      NOT NULL,
  estCost     DECIMAL(8, 2) NOT NULL,
  estAudience INTEGER       NOT NULL,
  budNo       CHAR(30),
  CONSTRAINT EventReqtPK PRIMARY KEY (evntNo),
  CONSTRAINT FK_Facility FOREIGN KEY (facNo) REFERENCES Facility (facNo),
  CONSTRAINT FK_Customer FOREIGN KEY (custNo) REFERENCES Customer (custNo)

);

INSERT INTO EventReq (evntNo, custNo, facNo, dateHeld, dateReq, dateAuth, status, estCost, estAudience, budNo)
VALUES ('E100', 'C100', 'F100', TO_DATE('2013-10-25','YYYY-MM-DD'), TO_DATE('2013-06-06','YYYY-MM-DD'), TO_DATE('2013-06-08','YYYY-MM-DD'), 'Approved', 5000.00, 80000, 'B1000');
```

My exact error is

```
INSERT INTO EventReq (evntNo, custNo, facNo, dateHeld, dateReq, dateAuth, status, estCost, estAudience, budNo)
VALUES ('E100', 'C100', 'F100', TO_DATE('2013-10-25','YYYY-MM-DD'), TO_DATE('2013-06-06','YYYY-MM-DD'), TO_DATE('2013-06-08','YYYY-MM-DD'), 'Approved', 5000.00, 80000, 'B1000')
Error report -
ORA-02291: integrity constraint (SYSTEM.FK_FACILITY) violated - parent key not found
```

I just want to add the value to the table and I am unable to do so...
Would be great if someone could help me out!

Comment: Tip: Have integer primary keys, don't try to add some kind of "information" into them, like the F or C prefixes. Also, your facNo columns have inconsistent data types...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CHAR` is a poor choice, unless you know that all values will be fixed length. Why? Because Oracle right-pads those values with spaces, up to the maximum column length.

This is what you did:

```
SQL> desc facility;
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 FACNO                                     NOT NULL CHAR(11)           --> 11 characters
 FACNAME                                   NOT NULL VARCHAR2(30)

SQL> select facno, length(facno) lenfac, 'x' || facno ||'x' xfac from facility;

FACNO           LENFAC XFAC
----------- ---------- -------------
F100                11 xF100       x
F101                11 xF101       x      
                            -------
                            1234567 spaces
SQL>
```

See?

- column length = 11
- value you stored was `F100`
- it is stored as `F100` + 7 spaces, 11 characters in length in total

That wouldn't make problem while inserting into `eventreq` table, but - you said that it accepts 11 characters into the `facno` column:

```
SQL> desc eventreq
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 EVNTNO                                    NOT NULL CHAR(8)
 CUSTNO                                    NOT NULL CHAR(8)
 FACNO                                     NOT NULL CHAR(8)         --> 8 characters
 DATEHELD                                  NOT NULL DATE
 DATEREQ                                   NOT NULL DATE
 DATEAUTH                                           DATE
 STATUS                                    NOT NULL CHAR(20)
 ESTCOST                                   NOT NULL NUMBER(8,2)
 ESTAUDIENCE                               NOT NULL NUMBER(38)
 BUDNO                                              CHAR(30)

SQL>
```

It means that - when you're inserting a row into the `eventreq` table, `facno = F100` which is right-padded with spaces up to column length which is here **8** characters (i.e. `F100` + 4 spaces).

Compare:

```
facility - facno char(11)
eventreq - facno char(8)
```

F100 right-padded to 8 characters is different from F100 right-padded to 11 characters, and that's why Oracle said that it couldn't find a matching parent key.

What to do?

- shorten `facno` column in `facility` table to 8 characters

  - or enlarge that column in `eventreq` to 11 characters
- change datatype to `VARCHAR2`

For example, if both columns are `CHAR(8)`:

```
SQL> desc facility
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 FACNO                                     NOT NULL CHAR(8)
 FACNAME                                   NOT NULL VARCHAR2(30)

SQL> select * From facility;

FACNO    FACNAME
-------- ------------------------------
F100     Football stadium

SQL> desc eventreq;
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 EVNTNO                                    NOT NULL CHAR(8)
 CUSTNO                                    NOT NULL CHAR(8)
 FACNO                                     NOT NULL CHAR(8)
 DATEHELD                                  NOT NULL DATE
 DATEREQ                                   NOT NULL DATE
 DATEAUTH                                           DATE
 STATUS                                    NOT NULL CHAR(20)
 ESTCOST                                   NOT NULL NUMBER(8,2)
 ESTAUDIENCE                               NOT NULL NUMBER(38)
 BUDNO                                              CHAR(30)

SQL> INSERT INTO EventReq (evntNo, custNo, facNo, dateHeld, dateReq, dateAuth, status, estCost, estAudience, budNo)
  2  VALUES ('E100', 'C100', 'F100', TO_DATE('2013-10-25','YYYY-MM-DD'), TO_DATE('2013-06-06','YYYY-MM-DD'), TO_DATE('2013-06-08','YYYY-MM-DD'), 'Appr
oved', 5000.00, 80000, 'B1000');

1 row created.

SQL>
```

It *works*.

---

Finally, a **HUGE** mistake:

> SYSTEM.FK_FACILITY

Do not use `SYSTEM` (nor `SYS`) users for anything but database administration. They aren't meant to be used for purposes like yours.